# pulseaudio --start E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Не удалось запустить демон

Tags: linux, archlinux, xfce, alsa, pulseaudio

Использую Arch Linux, XFCE4. Демон PulseAudio не запускается ни приложениями, ни "pulseaudio --start", ни "start-pulseaudio-x11". Переустановка не помогла. в /etc/pulse/client.conf autospawn = yes. Что делать?

Comment: *Что делать?*: 1. удостовериться, что запускаете от имени рядового пользователя. 2. удостовериться, что не запущены другие процессы pulseaudio. 3. попытаться разобраться с причиной падения самостоятельно, либо, собрав необходимую информацию, направить отчёт об ошибке мэйнтэйнерам пакета.

Comment: «в системном мониторе». нда. нда. ну, я вижу в вашем случае только один возможный вариант дальнейших действий: «направить отчёт об ошибке мэйнтэйнерам пакета»

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что папка "/home/user" принадлежала root